# ¿Como puedo leer el contenido de un PDF y exportarlo a .txt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, jspdf

Les explico lo que tengo, tengo esta aplicacion que hace algo similar a http://spritzinc.com/ la diferencia es que lee un archivo .txt y procesa el texto. Hasta alli todo bien, ahora quisiera hacer lo mismo con un PDF pero cuando muestro el contenido de dicho PDF se muestran unos caracteres raros, mi pregunta es: ¿Es posible leer al archivo PDF y convertirlo a .txt?

```js
     $( document ).ready(function() {
          spritz_pause();
        });

        function leerArchivo(e) {
          var archivo = e.target.files[0];
          if (!archivo) {
            return;
          }
          var lector = new FileReader();
          lector.onload = function(e) {
            var contenido = e.target.result;
            mostrarContenido(contenido);
          };
          lector.readAsText(archivo);
        }

        function mostrarContenido(contenido) {
          var elemento = document.getElementById('contenido-archivo');
          elemento.innerHTML = contenido;
          clearInterval(spritz);
          words_set();
          i = 0;
          spritz_play();
        }

        document.getElementById('file-input')
        .addEventListener('change', leerArchivo, false);


        var wpm = $('#spritz_wpm').val();
        var interval = 60000/wpm;
        var paused = false;
        var $space = $('.spritz-word');
        var i = 1;

        /* TEXT PARSING */
        function words_set() {
          words = $('.demo-text').val().trim()
          .replace(/([-—])(\w)/g, '$1 $2')
          .replace(/[\r\n]/g, ' {linebreak} ')
          .replace(/\. /g, '. {period} ')
          .replace(/[ \t]{2,}/g, ' ')
          .split(' ');
          for (var j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            words[j] = words[j].replace(/{linebreak}|{period}/g, '   ');
          }
        }
        /* ON EACH WORD */
        function word_show(i) {
          var word = words[i];
          var stop = Math.round((word.length+1)*0.4)-1;
          $space.html('<div>'+word.slice(0,stop)+'</div><div>'+word[stop]+'</div><div>'+word.slice(stop+1)+'</div>');
        }
        /* ITERATION FUNCTION */
        function word_update() {
          spritz = setInterval(function() {
            word_show(i);
            i++;
            if (i == words.length) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                $space.html('');
                spritz_pause();
              }, interval);
              clearInterval(spritz);
            };
          }, interval);
        }

        /* PAUSING FUNCTIONS */
        function spritz_pause() {
          clearInterval(spritz);
          paused = true;
          $('#spritz_pause').addClass('paused');
        }
        function spritz_play() {
          word_update();
          paused = false;
          $('#spritz_pause').removeClass('paused');
        }
        function spritz_flip() {
          if (paused) {
            spritz_play();
          } else {
            spritz_pause();
          }
        }

        /* INITIATE */
        words_set();
        word_show(0);
        word_update();

        /* CHANGE SPEED */
        $('#spritz_wpm').on('input', function() {
          interval = 60000/$('#spritz_wpm').val();
          if (!paused) {
            clearInterval(spritz);
            word_update();
          }
        });

        /* REFRESH TEXT */
        $('#spritz_change').on('click', function() {
          clearInterval(spritz);
          words_set();
          i = 0;
          spritz_play();
        });

        /* PAUSE BUTTON AND SPACE BAR */
        $('#spritz_pause').on('click', function() {
          spritz_flip();
          return false;
        });
        $(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 32) {
            spritz_flip();
          }
        })


        /* LIGHT/DARK THEME */
        $('.light').on('click', function() {
          $('html').toggleClass('night');
          return false;
        });
```

```css
     .spritz {
          position: relative;
          border-top: 2px solid #000;
          border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
          padding: 2rem 0 1.2rem;

        }

        .spritz:before, .spritz:after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          left: 40%;
          height: 0.2rem;
          width: 10px;
          margin-left: -1px;
          background-color: #000;
        }

        .spritz-word {
          font-size: 5rem;
          line-height: 5rem;
          height: 5.5rem;
          font-weight: 600;
        }

        .spritz-word div {
          display: table-cell;
        }
        .spritz-word div:first-child {
          width: 40%;
          text-align: right;
        }
        .spritz-word div:nth-child(2) {
          color: #e60000;
        }
        .night .spritz-word div:nth-child(2) {
          color: #ff4d4d;
        }
        .spritz-word div:last-child {
          width: 60%;
          text-align: left;
        }
        .row{
          margin: 5rem auto;
          justify-content: center;
          display: flex;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      </head>

      <body> 
        <h1 class="text-center">Ejemplo Lector Como Spritz</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="spritz col-md-3"> 
            <div class="spritz-word"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="settings col-md-4">
            <input type="file" id="file-input" class="form-control" />
            <input class="form-control" id="spritz_wpm" type="number" value="300" step="50" min="50"/>
            <button class="btn btn-danger pause" id="spritz_pause"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger pause" id="spritz_change"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i></button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container-fluid"><textarea class="demo-text form-control" id="contenido-archivo" rows="15">_</textarea></div>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Es posible, obviamente del lado del servidor, si estas usando un servidor Linux ya estas del otro lado, existe un programa que puedes ejecutar desde la linea de comandos y este lee y genera un txt en base a un pdf, puedes hacer la llamada del bash desde PHP https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/converter-pdf-files-to-text-format-command/

Comment: @M.Gress esto no es posible con JavaScript? gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba con el framework [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) aunque creo que solo funciona con HTML5 [Aqui](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples) algunos ejemplos de como leer un PDF sin que te salgan caracteres raros [Aqui](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript) un ejemplo de como extraer únicamente texto

Comment: Hasta donde yo se, no es posible, porque necesitas hacer uso de un OCR y hasta donde he visto esto no es posible del lado del cliente, la única forma que al menos yo conozco y que he probado es del lado del servidor.

Comment: No he podido hacerlo con un PDF :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) es posible y usando [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) puedes crear un archivo y agregarlo para descarga en un link usando el atributo `download`.

**Código ES8**

```
const fileToBinary = file => new Promise((resolve) => {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = function() {
    const b64 = reader.result.split(',')[1]
    const binary = atob(b64)
    resolve(binary)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
})

PDFJS.disableWorker = true

const getDocument = (source, isURL) => {
  if (isURL) {
    return PDFJS.getDocument(source)
  }
  return PDFJS.getDocument({ data: source })
}

const getPages = async (doc) => {
  const numPages = doc.numPages
  const pages = []
  for (let i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
    pages.push(await doc.getPage(i + 1))
  }
  return pages
}

const convertToText = async (source) => {
  const doc = await getDocument(source)
  const pages = await getPages(doc)
  const contents = []

  for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    const content = await pages[i].getTextContent()
    const text = 
          content
            .items
            .reduce((acc, item) => (acc.str || acc) + item.str)
    contents.push(text)
  }
  return contents
}

async function processPDF(pdf) {
  const binary = await fileToBinary(pdf)
  const contents = await convertToText(binary, false)
  const text = contents.join('\n')
  const download = document.getElementById('download')
  download.classList.remove('hidden')
  const blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain '})
  download.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
}
```

El código anterior permite que el usuario suba un PDF y a continuación, este es convertido a base64 para finalmente convertirlo a una forma binaria para que pueda ser procesado por PDF.js. Finalmente, crea un Blob a partir del texto y construye una URL para descarga.

---

**Demo**

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcional en [este Pen](https://codepen.io/gugadev/full/eEoPKZ/).

---

**PD**

Si quieres usar el código en producción, primero transpílalo a ES5 con [Babel](https://babeljs.io).